# Automapper Map from outer class to inner class variable

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper and need to know whether I can map a source variable to a nested member variable?

This is the source I want to map from

```
public class source
{
    public string name;
}
```

This is the destination - I need the name variable assigned to the Nested.Name member

```
public class Destination
{
    public Nested info;
}

public class Nested
{
    public string name;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Ron.

Comment: Do you have an explicit defined configuration?

Comment: I have no idea what the Mapper.Initialize CreateMap definition would be.

Answer (score 2):

`ForPath` would do the trick

```
CreateMap<source, Destination>()
        .ForPath(d => d.info.name, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, although you might run into an uninitialized `dst.info`

```
CreateMap<source, Destination>()
            //reegular mapping here
            .ForMember(dst => dst.foo, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.otherfoo))
            //AfterMap to bind your properties
            .AfterMap((src, dst) => { dst.info.name = src.name; });
```

Comment: Yep it complains with this -> must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Comment: Ah, aftermap can safe you indeed... let me fix an example